# Why can't I to iterate MongoDb object in loop for Meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, meteor, d3plus

I've a issue in my app in Meteor.js. The issue is that i wanna to fill an array with a loop for over the MongoDB objects like this:

```
var sample_data = []

for(i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
        sample_data[i] = {"citas": {{#each scraper}}{{publicaciones.[i].citas}}{{/each}}, autores: "{{#each scraper}}{{publicaciones.[i].authors}}{{/each}}",titulo: "{{#each scraper}}{{publicaciones.[i].titulo_pub}}{{/each}}"}
        sample_data.fill(sample_data[i], i, i + 1);
      }

     var visualization = d3plus.viz()
       .container("#viz")
       .data(sample_data)
       .type("tree_map")
       .id(["titulo", "autores"])
       .size("citas")
       .draw()
```

[image]

I don't understand why i can`t to fill this array. I was testing this sentence

```
sample_data[i] = {"citas": {{#each scraper}}{{publicaciones.[i].citas}}{{/each}}, autores: "{{#each scraper}}{{publicaciones.[i].authors}}{{/each}}",titulo: "{{#each scraper}}{{publicaciones.[i].titulo_pub}}{{/each}}"}
```

But instead of (i) i set a static value, for example (6). And this work really fine, like this:

```
sample_data[i] = {"citas": {{#each scraper}}{{publicaciones.[6].citas}}{{/each}}, autores: "{{#each scraper}}{{publicaciones.[6].authors}}{{/each}}",titulo: "{{#each scraper}}{{publicaciones.[6].titulo_pub}}{{/each}}"}
```

And this is my helper template.

---

```
Template.script.helpers({
  scraper : function() {
    return Scrapers.find({id_usuario : Busquedas.findOne({sec : Busquedas.find().count()}).id_investigador});
  }
```

**Please I hope a advice o any kind of help to solve this. Thanks so much to all.**

Comment: Wrap this in quotes? `"{{#each scraper}}{{publicaciones.[6].citas}}{{/each}}"`

Comment: I tried that and it did not work :/

Comment: {{#each scraper}}{{publicaciones.[6].citas}}{{/each}} must be a integer number

Comment: I don't really understand what file is this? You are mixing javascript and blaze in the same file?

Comment: yes, i'm mixing javascript and blaze. I need to render mongodb records in graphs d3plus in javascript. it is understood?